# redux framework wordpress calling variable

Tags: templates, wordpress, redux-framework

I have installed the redux plugin via wordpress and great and all.

I have been using the demo content to get the used to the framework, but I can't figure out how to call the data in the template?

I have been using option tree for a long time and figured that one out..

this is what I thought would be the proper call out but I guess not..

This is the code I thought would get the logo uploaded.

```
<?php global $redux_demo; echo $redux_demo['media'];?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?  `<?php global $redux_demo; echo $redux_demo['media']['url'];?>`

Answer (score 1):

Redux Framework create an array of MEDIA

You can access MEDIA info i.e.

1. Define `global $redux_demo;`
2. To access

   1. ID   : `echo $redux_demo['media']['id'];`
   2. TYPE : `echo $redux_demo['media']['type'];`
   3. URL  : `echo $redux_demo['media']['url'];`

etc.

For more details refer https://github.com/ReduxFramework/ReduxFramework/wiki/Fields

Answer (score 0):

You can also shorthand it:  $GLOBALS['redux_demo']