# Redux WP Framework. A simple working code example?

Tags: php, wordpress, callback, wordpress-theming, redux-framework

Can anyone who successfully used this framework help me?
Redux states that it utilizes a global variable for referencing all of the *saved* options in the database.

My goal is to access these stored options, so I can figure out how to call them.

Admittedly, I am new to using options panel frameworks. There is another similar question at: [redux framework wordpress calling variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107180/redux-framework-wordpress-calling-variable). I can't figure out using the documentation how this is done.

Here is the documentation for the framework: http://plovs.github.io/Redux-Framework-Docs/docs.html

What am I missing? The section/field arrays look like this:

```
    $sections[] = array(
    'title' => __('Home Settings', 'redux-framework-demo'),
    'desc' => __('Here, you can change any of the many options bundled with samTheme', 'redux-framework-demo'),
    'icon' => 'el-icon-home',
    // 'submenu' => false, // Setting submenu to false on a given section will hide it from the WordPress sidebar menu!
    'fields' => array(  
        array(
            'id'=>'webFonts',
            'type' => 'media', 
            'title' => __('Web Fonts', 'redux-framework-demo'),
            'compiler' => 'true',
            'mode' => false, // Can be set to false to allow any media type, or can also be set to any mime type.
            'desc'=> __('Basic media uploader with disabled URL input field.', 'redux-framework-demo'),
            'subtitle' => __('Upload any media using the WordPress native uploader', 'redux-framework-demo'),
            ),
```

The $sections[] array id is generic in name. The arrays are generic in name. I'm assuming these can be referenced by id? This is ultra confusing. If I'm missing something ridiculous here, I apologise in advance. I'm completely new to this framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too found Redux Framework confusing at first.

I think what you're trying to do (assuming this is still the case, as it's an old question) is output the value of the Redux Framework *opt_name* variable.

Find the value of *opt_name* in your options/config file.  Using the [sample config file](https://github.com/ReduxFramework/redux-framework/blob/master/sample/sample-config.php) as an example, opt_name is defined as *redux_demo*.

So armed with that, head over to your functions.php page (or any of your theme's pages as an example) and declare

`global $redux_demo;`

followed by

`echo $redux_demo['webFonts']['url'];`

That should output the URL saved within the webFonts section of your options panel.  You can find a list of available fields along with more example code at http://docs.reduxframework.com/core/fields/media/

Comment: How can we make Redux less confusing? I'd love to get your input on docs and how to improve them.

Comment: @Dovy I can't speak for others but I learn by examples, so a quick start demo with code works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Spoiler alert, I am a core dev of Redux, ha.

So the best place to get support is our issue tracker found here: https://github.com/ReduxFramework/ReduxFramework/issues

But, I'll answer this here.

The docs you have are old, really old, like 2 years old. Redux is a completely new setup now. Please look here: https://github.com/ReduxFramework/ReduxFramework/wiki/Getting-Started#step-3-using-the-saved-option-values

That should answer all your questions. Let me know if you need further help!

Comment: Links may be old in some years too. Stop fishing for visitors and just answer the question here with example code - that is what stackoverflow is for.

Answer (score 0):

In Config file find:

```
$opt_name = 'your_opt_name';
```

In functions.php or in theme:

```
global $your_opt_name;

echo $your_opt_name['webFonts'];
```

Or you can debug to get full info:

```
var_dump($your_opt_name)
```